# Getting highcharts series and data being currently displayed in container at runtime

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts

The legacy code spans over many files and lines so i apologize for not posting any code.

My scenario is I am having some angular js front end UI which uses highcharts. Each chart has about 2 to 5 series and the data for series are retrieved from the Spring MVC backend get request.
What I want to do is, calculate the overall min position of all the series in highchart window currently being dispayed(calculate min value for only visible series and zoomed area) and below that plot another series(call it 'Target' series) dynamically.

At present, the front end is like, when sending a get request to backend, based on the data returned, the min position is calculated and plotted as horizontal line at some y axis. But when we hide any series or zoom any chart, the 'X' series still remains in same y axis, since its calculated at beginning itself.

Is there any way to get my task done? I tried chart.events.redraw to intercept during every redraw. But I dont know how to get the current chart series and data currently being displayed on the container at runtime.

There are separate functions already defined for calculating min position from the series and data. So I need to know, how to find the chart current visible series and data inside chart.events.redraw ? Thanks in advance...:)

```
options: {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
      redraw: function() {
        redraw: function(event) {
        var eventExtrems = [];
        eventExtrems[0] = Math.min();
        eventExtrems[1] = Math.max();
        // var selectedSeries = $scope.joltsVsNovaLiveJobsConfig.series;
        var selectedSeries = this.series;
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedSeries.length; i++) {
            if(selectedSeries[i].name != 'Events' && selectedSeries[i].data.length != 0 && selectedSeries[i].visible){
              var dataset = selectedSeries[i].data;
              var extrems = [];
              extrems[0] = Math.min.apply(Math,dataset.map(function(item){return item.y;}));
              extrems[1] = Math.max.apply(Math,dataset.map(function(item){return item.y;}));
              eventExtrems[0] = eventExtrems[0] > extrems[0] ? extrems[0] : eventExtrems[0];
              eventExtrems[1] = eventExtrems[1] < extrems[1] ? extrems[1] : eventExtrems[1];
            }
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < selectedSeries.length; i++) {
            if(selectedSeries[i].name == 'Events'){
              eventExtrems[0] = eventExtrems[0] !== Math.min() ? eventExtrems[0] : 0;
              eventExtrems[1] = eventExtrems[1] !== Math.max() ? eventExtrems[1] : 0;
              var yValue = eventExtrems[0] - ((eventExtrems[1] - eventExtrems[0]) * 0.1);
              _.each(this.series[i].data, function(item) {
                item.y = yValue;
              });
              this.series[i].setData(selectedSeries[i].data, false);
              this.series[i].isDirty = true;
              // chart.redraw();
            }

          }
      }
    }
  },...
```

Comment: You can access series via this.series and filter them if they are visible. For accessing data - series.points. See example http://jsfiddle.net/pcf5vbz5/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to update one of my series data y values inside this redraw function. What is happening is, it is updating the y value when chart is redrawn, but not reflected in chart.. Only in next chart redrawn, the changed values are reflected.

Comment: You can redraw inside the redraw event, but you need to to set some flag to prevent infinite looping - http://jsfiddle.net/pcf5vbz5/1/

Comment: yes. yesterday one senior in my office helped me with that. I just left that thought thinking it will go into an infintie loop like that. My fault. Thank u so much for your response.